# ambiguous option error with optparse

Tags: python, optparse

Please tell why the below code is giving the error though both indicates the same option.

```
In [3]: parser = optparse.OptionParser()

In [4]: parser.add_option("--currencies", "--currency", "--ccy")
Out[4]: <Option at 0x7f113e6c4488: --currencies/--currency/--ccy>

In [5]: parser.parse_args(["--curr", "CHF"])
Usage: ipython [options]

ipython: error: ambiguous option: --curr (--currencies, --currency?)
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no real docs about this, but you can check [the source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/optparse.py#L1675) and see what happen.

In brief, `optparse` will check if given arguments are not too close from each other.

If two arguments (or more) starts by the same string (like `foo`, `foobar` and `foofoo` which all starts by `foo`) it will raise an `AmbiguousOptionError`.

In your case, `--currencies` and `--currency` starts by `--curr`, so when you ask to parse `--curr` `optparse` cannot say if you want to say `--currency` or `--currencies`.

Comment: I suppose as a crude workaround you can also add `--curr` (and maybe `--curre` and `--curren` and `--currenc`) as aliases. But I'd call this a bug.

Answer (score 2):

If you use "argparse" instead of "optparse", then you can add "allow_abbrev=False" attribute to ignore this error.

Answer (score 0):

Add all the abbreviation of both options e.g. for -filter and -file:

```
parser.add_argument('-filter', '-file', '-f', '-fi', '-fil', '-filt', '-filte')
```

Now -filter, -file, -f, -fi, -fil, -filt, -filte will work.